# How to save options along with a query

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I save selected query options along with a query in BigQuery Web UI.

I have some queries that I will use to periodically overwrite a table.  How can I save the appropriate options along with the Query?  (Currently the query SQL language is saved, but the query options appear to be whatever I last used in a "compose query" action.

Comment: Why not save a `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and will work for you if you only want to replace/overwrite your table

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.table` 
AS <Your Query>
```

You can <kbd>Save Query</kbd> and then use it from <kbd>Saved Queries</kbd>

See more about [`DDL's CREATE TABLE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement)